# How to fix my batch for loop to store the last line?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, skip-lists

I have a file called cmd.pid and in this file i store the pid of all cmd.exe running on the computer.

I need to store the last line of the file (because its the last cmd open)

This is to send commands on the cmd window thanks to the pid i save.

```
for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%i in ('type "mypath\cmd.pid"') do set "line=%%i" & goto done
:done
echo line^=!line!
```

The value of the 3rd line of my file isn't in !line!
The program stop when i launch it.

This is what my cmd.pid file store :

```
16992      

12300
```

The first line is 16992, 2nd line is blank and the last line is 12300.
You can't see it but there is spaces (6 exactly) after each pid

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "mypath\cmd.pid"') do set /a "line=%%i"`

Comment: Would using `Sort` help?

Comment: Your code skips the first two lines and then returns the content of the next non-blank line that does not begin with `;` (due to the default `eol` option); to return the last such line just remove the `& goto done` portion...

Comment: I can't access to my code now but this night i gonna see if it work without the goto. If it didn't wotk i will see with sort command. And check Mofi website. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I find where was the crash problem, it was from the name of aa file with spaces (so i rename this folder) But there is a new problem, when i launch the script it say `Missing Operand`this is my new for loop :`for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%i in ('type "mypath\cmd.pid"') do set /a "line=%%i"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way would have been to remove the instruction

```
goto done
```

and remove the `skip=?` entirely (although it would do no harm.)

That way, each value read from the file is assigned to `line` in turn, so the very last value remains when the `for` loop terminates at the end-of-file.

Answer (score 0):

The problems was:

- A folder in my path had a space => I renamed it to remove the space
- 1st problem with the loop: `Missing Operand`=> I removed the `/a` of `do set /a "line=%%i"` because I don't use it
- 2nd problem with the loop: `ECHO is off` it was happening when `echo !line!` was out of the loop but was working when it was in the loop so I used a `goto` at the end of the loop to leave it. Now I can `echo !line!` outside of the loop without any problem.
- 3rd problem was to use `skip=2 delims=`. I don't know why, but it was "unexpected".

This is the final loop code:

```
for /f "delims= skip=1" %%i in ('type "mypath\cmd.pid"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    goto done
)
:done
echo !line!
pause
```

This code doesn't add a "0" at the end of the pid and you can select the n line by using `skip=n-1`.